# Doesn't work click event on input by native js

Tags: javascript

I have html markup

```
<div id="site">
<header id="masthead">
    <h1>Winery</h1>
</header>

<a href="cart.html" class="linkcart">Go to Shopping Cart <span></span></a>
<div id="content">
    <div id="products">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
            <li >
                <div class="product-image">
                    <img data-bind="attr:{src: img}" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="product-description">
                    <h3 class="product-name"><span data-bind="text: name" /></h3>
                    <span class="product-id">ID <span data-bind="text: id" /></span></span>
                    <p class="product-price">&euro;  <span data-bind="text: price" /></p>
                    <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                    <span class="down" ></span>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: qty" class="qty" />
                    <span class="up"></span><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" id="add" />
                </div>
            </li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="browser">

    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to hang a click event on input by native js, but event doesn't work on input

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('browser').remove();
}
```

If assign a handler through attribute html tag it's works

```
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" id="add"  onclick="addToBlock()"/>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',function(){
document.getElementById('browser').remove();});

Comment: Where is your browser element? And the addToBlock() function?

Comment: @damianocelent: If the OP's code isn't working, that won't work either. Yes, it's better to play nicely with others (e.g., DOM2 handlers), but the old stuff does work.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure your assignment of the event handler happens after the document has loaded, so for instance in `window.onload = function () { ... }`

Comment: the 'browser' element not defined

Comment: My guess is that you're running your code *before* the element exists. Move the `script` to the bottom of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Does that have any `<form>` element outer `<div id="products">`? If yes, maybe it is due to the form submitting. If not, it is good that check the browser console and see the error message.

Comment: In console any error message, browser element is defined after <div id="content">, doesn't any form element, script included in the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in ID, I have a few elements with the same ID and onclick work only for first element. I get by class

```
//get all input by class
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
//add onclick to each
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the document is loaded before assigning event handlers:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('browser').remove();
    }
};
```

If you use `jQuery`, you could have it execute potentially earlier than with the above code, as it does not wait for images to be loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('#browser').remove();
    });
});
```

Executing it straight away, but by moving the code at the bottom of your document, like after the close of your `body` tag will work in most cases, although I have had deeply nested `DOM` hierarchies where this could fail:

```
...
</body>
<script>
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('browser').remove();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

If you go for that last option, but want to add some precaution, but the code in a `setTimeout` with delay `0`, which will make it run asynchronously allowing the `DOM` to be completely built:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('browser').remove();
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: `window.onload` is just about the worst way to do that, however, as it happens only after all images and other ancillary resources are loaded.

Comment: Can you provide more `html` in your question so we can see the browser element? With what you have provided so far the `window.onload` method works for me, it is just that on click I get an error that 'browser' is not defined.

Comment: edited, now you can see browser element, in the bottom before </body> included main.js with event onclick

Comment: where do you close the `<div id="site">` tag?

Comment: Anyway, I put your code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r65f5cuj/). I only added some text in the "browser" `div`. And it works. Please check it. Does this fiddle not work for you?

Comment: interesting, in fiddle work..but in project no, thank you for trying, i will use onclick attribute

Comment: It could be that you have other scripts included that reinitialise `window.onload`. You could still try one of the other options in my answer (e.g. with `setTimeout`).

Comment: I tried other options, but they doesn't work to, if add id="add" to another element, for example <h1 id="add">Winery</h1> it work's by document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {}, so how it may not work for input..